# Gmail not redirect to particular account?

Tags: gmail

When I enter this (https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=santosh@gmail.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/santosh@gmail.com/) in browser and no other Gmail account is currently logged in, it will ask for the password for santosh@gmail.com, but if I've already logged in using another email it just open that account's inbox and does not ask me to enter a password for santosh@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin` is the address for logging in to the Gmail initially. To add accounts after there's one already signed in you ned to use `https://accounts.google.com/AddSession`.

In your case it'll be:

https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?service=mail&passive=true&Email=santosh@gmail.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/santosh@gmail.com/